# Algorithms for the Lakes of Wada

Tags: gn.general-topology, algorithms

The Lakes of Wada partitions the unit square in to three regions, all of whom share a common boundary. The Wikipedia entry (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada) gives a construction approach, and a picture of a first few steps of the construction.

Is there a good algorithm available somewhere to explicitly list the partition up to some specific iteration? Or a closed form expression for the boundary in the limit of the process?

I'm hoping for something I can implement myself, or a piece of software that already does it, and in the end get a picture to arbitrary high levels of detail and arbitrary high iterations of the construction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wada lakes can be obtained following a recipe given by Plykin.
An algorithm is explained in an online [article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200601/fea-coudene.pdf) in the Notices of the AMS. You only need to iterate a single explicit function to get the picture. So, this can be done using any fractal generator (`chaospro`,`fractint`,...). Note that zooming on
the boundary of the lake is not so interesting. You only get straight interlaced color bands after a few zooms.

The result can be seen [online](http://www.math.univ-brest.fr/perso/yves.coudene/dyn3.html) (scroll to the section about Wada Lakes). There is also a [movie](http://www.math.univ-brest.fr/perso/yves.coudene/lakes.avi).

Actually there are four regions on the pictures/movie. You can merge two of them if three is enough for your need.

Cheers

Comment: But if I merge two regions, then those two will no longer be homeomorphic to disks, right?

Comment:  Yes, sorry. Merging is not the correct word. You can use the method to produce any finite number of lakes, just by adding/removing attracting periodic points. You can get three lakes by removing the perturbation at the origin, for example.

Comment: I also wonder whether you are making the distinction that Wikipedia is making between *Lakes of Wada* and *Basins of Wada*; what I really want is a partition of the unit square, preferably in roughly equal size pieces, with the wada property. 

Comment: I believe a countably infinite number of lakes can actually be produced.

Comment: Which function exactly one needs to iterate in order to obtain the basins of attraction shown in the movie? Sorry but I got a bit confused.